# How to get extent of filtered WMS layer and how to zoom it with OpenLayers 4?

Tags: openlayers

I am looking for zoom to filtered WMS layer, but it is not working. I am using OpenLayers 4 with GeoServer. How to get the extent of filtered WMS layer. I tried in API but it is not able applicable. Here is the my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Integrated Land Records Management System</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
        <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
        <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
        <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js"></script>
        <style>  
            .print_button {  
                position: absolute;  
                z-index: 100;  
                right: 20px;  
                top: 20px;    
            }
            .bhucode {
                margin-left: 30px;
            } 
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
      Select Bhucode 
      <select id="bhucode" class="bhucode" >
        <option value="">Select Bhucode</option>
      </select>
        <div id="map" class="map">
        </div>   
        
        <script>
          var wmsSource = new ol.source.TileWMS({
            url: 'http://localhost:9090/geoserver/ilfs/wms',
            params: {'LAYERS': 'ilfs:dharani_samplevillage', 
                'TILED': true, 'format': 'image/png', 
                'VERSION': '1.1.1', 'SRS':'EPSG:4326',          
                    "TRANSPARENT": true,
                    "ISBASELAYER": true,
                    "RATIO": 1,
                    "TILED": true,
                    "CQL_FILTER": "bhucode=11223344444555 and kid=243"
            },
            serverType: 'geoserver',
            transition: 0
            //crossOrigin: 'anonymous'      
          });
          
          var wmsLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
              source: wmsSource,
              opacity: 0.7,
              visible: true          
          });
          
          var view = new ol.View({
              projection: 'EPSG:4326',        
              center: [0, 0],
              zoom: 18            
          });
          
          var map = new ol.Map({
              layers: [wmsLayer],
              target: 'map',
              view: view,
              renderer: 'canvas'
          });
          
          console.log("Layer Extent : "+wmsLayer.getSource().getExtent());
          
          var extent = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());
          console.log("Extent - "+ extent);    
          
          map.getView().fit(wmsLayer.getExtent(), map.getSize());
          
          var centerMap = map.getView().getCenter();
          console.log("Center : "+ centerMap);      
          map.getView().setCenter(centerMap);              
          
          var srs = JSON.stringify(view.getProjection().getCode());
            //ol.proj.Projection
          console.log("View SRS : "+srs);
          console.log("WMSSource SRS : "+ JSON.stringify(wmsSource.params));
      </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

How can I alter the above code to get the extent, and how to apply the extent to below:
`map.getView().fitExtent(extent, map.getSize());`

Comment: Using filters does not change the extent of a WMS layer. The map is still covering the same area but some features are just not rendered on the map. Read the geometries from WFS service with the same filter `"CQL_FILTER": "bhucode=11223344444555 and kid=243"`and then you will have something to zoom into.